# Calculating predicted probabilities for ordinal logistic regression

Tags: r, regression, ordered-logit

I've run an ordered logistic regression model in R with Zelig and am looking to calculate predicted probabilities. Zelig has a series of simple one line commands to generate the information I want on first differences and so forth. Unfortunately, I keep getting an error when running the zelig function and was wondering if there was a quick alternative for generating predicted probabilities for a ordered logit in R.

For what it's worth, here's the error from my Zelig code.

```
> x.out <- setx(mod, credit=1)
Error in dta[complete.cases(mf), names(dta) %in% vars, drop = FALSE] : 
  incorrect number of dimensions
```

I just need an alternative solution that I can use to generate the probabilities.

Comment: There is also a zelig list, you might get a solution to the error there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076633/logistic-regression-using-zelig-r) was raised on Stack Overflow more than one year ago. I don't know if re-installing Zelig and its dependencies will solve your problem (especially because I would prefer to understand why this error message came up before reinstalling).

Anyway, you can use the `lrm()` function from the [rms](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rms/index.html) package, as it allows to fit several models for categorical outcomes including proportional odds model. There is a `predict()` (but also `Predict()`) function to get the desired predicted values. As an alternative, you may want to look at the [ordinal](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ordinal/index.html) package (see the `clm()` function).

Comment: Thanks, re-installing did not help. I'll looking into the rms package.

Comment: For `rms` do `?predict.lrm` to see how to get all probabilities of interest.

Answer (score 0):

There is also `polr` in `MASS` that can fit the proportional odds cumulative logit model, which I like because you can show the fitted model easily using the `effects` package (for `lrm` and `clm` this is not the case I believe, except maybe with `Effect()` in the development version), and also get 95% confidence limits on your predictions. Here is a little example :

```
data=read.table("https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat504/sites/onlinecourses.science.psu.edu.stat504/files/lesson07/cheese.dat",col.names=c("cheese","response","count"))
data$response=factor(data$response, ordered=T)
fit=polr(response ~ cheese, weights=count, data=data)
summary(fit)
z=summary(fit)$coefficients/summary(fit)$standard.errors
p=(1 - pnorm(abs(z), 0, 1)) * 2 # 2-tailed Wald z tests to test significance of coefficients
p
Anova(fit, type="III")  # likelihood ratio tests for effect of different factors
library(colorRamps)
plot(allEffects(fit),ylab="Response",rescale.axis=F,style="stacked",colors=colorRampPalette(c("white","red"))(9))
```

[image]